# access SSIS Result Set Object Variable like an array

Tags: sql, variables, ssis, resultset

I am using the `Execute SQL Task` and have ResultSet set to `Single row`. I know in the `Result Set` section I can use column indexes to save the data in the result to different variables ([image: like so]).

I am wondering, if I save the entire row to a variable of type `Object`, is it possible to access the different columns of that variable like an array or something? I know I can do this in a `Script Task` but I wanted to do it in the expression builder.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There may be other ways to proceed.

Comment: Declutter the number of variables I'm creating. I have multiple containers in the same package that do the same thing for different data sources. Each container gets data for a source and stores it in variables. So I have to have multiple sets of variables for each container. I know I can scope each set to it's container but the overall number of variables is still high and ugly to me.

Comment: Designing for beauty is not a successful SSIS programming paradigm. ;)

Comment: Not just beauty, but ease of use and development. Having to create so many variables is just painful and leads to too many avenues for potential error.

Comment: If only Control Flow Package Parts were more functional then I could use them but they have so many of their own limitations they aren't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you can't access the data inside an object variable in an expression. Using a Script Task, or a Foreach Loop with an ADO Enumerator, are really the only ways to access the data inside the object.